# Make div appear intermittently using Animation css property not working

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

My goal is to have 4 colorful squares whose opacity goes from 0 to 1 intermittently to show something is loading.

I used css animation property (see below) to achieve that - but it doesn't work!

**CSS**

```
 animation: opacity 1.5s infinite 200ms
```

I have implemented it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgPPGb). Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have no keyframe animation assigned to you "opacity" animation. You need to create a keyframe animation for this to work:

(I changed the animation name to "fade" instead of "opacity")

**CSS**

```
.loader-block:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
    animation: fade 1.5s infinite 100ms;
}
...

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
} 

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/yaZZdr)**

**PS:** You also should close out all of your CSS properties with a semicolon (`;`). I noticed there were a few missing.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't have an animation called 'opacity' so there was no animation being called. In terms of a best practice -- you probably shouldn't have an animation have a name that's also a css property so I renamed it to blink.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALEEGQ

```
@keyframes blink{
  from {opacity: 1;} 
  to {opacity: 0; } 
}

.loader-block:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
    animation: blink 1.5s infinite 100ms;
}
...
```